# Ubuntu (18.04)/my PC can't boot on Windows (7)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

since I'm an engineer student (in programming), the need to use Linux is felt in order to be more efficient. So this afternoon I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer, with a dual boot.

I followed a guide provided by my teachers, I successfully finished my installation and then, when I reboot the PC, I can only boot on Ubuntu. So I immediately search on forums what could have gone wrong. *As I have two hard-disks, I install Linux on the other one a a new partition of the disk where **I didn't** install Windows, as it is better according to guide.*

First I checked problems with grub (which I didn't heard of before), and there was one small problem : the time of appearance was set to 0 so I changed it and apply the change but it didn't change anything.
Then I enter `lsblk` and `fdsisk -l /dev/sda` for both of my hard-disks following instructions of forums. And here is what I got:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0bBg.png).
I also installed and ran Grub Customizer and here is what I got :[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOF1x.png)

We can see here that my Windows boot isn't recognized as a boot but as a kind of directory (I can access to all files) and that Grub Customizer doesn't detect him. I also don't understand what is the label of my disk : `dos`
My guess is that during the installation, I had to add a EFI partition in order to make my installation successful. And my Windows doesn't need a EFI partition to boot, which makes it unavailable for booting (I'm not sure to be clear sorry).

Anyway, if you need details about a part that I skipped or if something was unclear, feel free to ask, and of course, thanks in advance for your answers guys.

*PS :* I barely talk about my installation because my post is already too long, and I apologize for such a long post.
*PPS :* I know there are other post with the same problem, but none of those I read was able to solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `boot-repair` on Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: If I had to make a wild gues, it would be: Your Windows is installed in BIOS-Mode and your Ubuntu is installed in UEFI-Mode, which can't be installed side by side.

Comment: I don't know if you'll see my message but thanks to both of you for your answers. 

So @xaander1 I tried running `boot-repair` but it didn't change a thing ... 

And @MelcomX, that's what I was approximately thinking. So if I understand well, I have to reinstall Windows with an EFI boot, right ? Is it complicated ? Is it a problem to install Windows after Linux (as some friends think) ?